# Low Precision of LeakyReLU

Tags: tensorflow, implementation, numerical, finite-precision

Dear TensorFlow experts,

I am trying to understand the following output of the TensorFlow LeakyReLU function, which seems to have very low precision:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')

import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=16)

tf.__version__ # 2.15.0 (newest)

alpha = 1./3.
x0 = np.array([np.array([-1., -1.])])

#----- EXPECTED RESULT ------
alpha*x0
# high precision output (as expected):
# returns: array([[-0.3333333333333333, -0.3333333333333333]])

#----- TENSORFLOW RESULT ------
tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=alpha)(x0).numpy()
# low precision output (not expected):
# array([[-0.3333333432674408, -0.3333333432674408]])
```

**I want to understand / my questions are**

1. Why is the numerical precision of the result so low?
2. Where is the numerical imprecision originating from (in detail)?

Regarding 2)
I have already located the `leaky_relu` source code under https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8e742eb385332ad4f53b4bbeeeec550e2bcc44a9/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L3670
but it calls a function gen_nn_ops.leaky_relu, which I am somehow unable to locate in the TensorFlow source code.

Answer (score 1):

The `alpha` parameter is `float32`.

````py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([-1, -1], dtype=np.float64)

alpha1 = np.array(1/3, dtype=np.float64)
(x * alpha1).tolist()
> [-0.3333333333333333, -0.3333333333333333]

alpha2 = np.array(1/3, dtype=np.float32)
(x * alpha2).tolist()
> [-0.3333333432674408, -0.3333333432674408]
```
````

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is confusing to me that TensorFlow casts alpha back into float32 even if I set the precision to float64. Do you think this is to be expected?